# Razor Foreach will only show last item in IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in my View which should iterate over a collection and i should see 14 images with different Names. But it will only show the last item in the collection.

Code i am using to display the images

```
        IEnumerable<Sector> sector = ViewBag.Sectors;

    <div id="js-grid-lightbox-gallery" class="cbp cbp-ready cbp-caption-active cbp-caption-overlayBottomAlong" style="height: 896px; margin:.5px 0px 0px 50px">
    <div class="cbp-wrapper-outer">
        <div class="cbp-wrapper">     
            @foreach (var item in sector)
            {
                <div class="cbp-item web-design graphic print motion" style="width: 389px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <div class="cbp-item-wrapper" style="">
                        <a href="ajax-lightbox-gallery/project1.html" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePageInline" data-title="World Clock<br>by Paul Flavius Nechita" rel="nofollow">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                                <img src="https://placeimg.com/380/285/arch" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignLeft">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">@item.Name</div>                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }                                         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code i am using to get the data.

```
     public IActionResult Experience(string sectorid)
    {

        IEnumerable<Sector> sector = sectorRepository.AllActive().ToList();
        ViewBag.Sectors = sector;

        return View();
    }
```

I cant See what i have done wrong. I have tried this as-well and i still get just the one image.

```
    <div id="js-grid-lightbox-gallery" class="cbp cbp-ready cbp-caption-active cbp-caption-overlayBottomAlong" style="height: 896px; margin:.5px 0px 0px 50px">
    <div class="cbp-wrapper-outer">
        <div class="cbp-wrapper">     
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="cbp-item web-design graphic print motion" style="width: 389px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                    <div class="cbp-item-wrapper" style="">
                        <a href="ajax-lightbox-gallery/project1.html" class="cbp-caption cbp-singlePageInline" data-title="World Clock<br>by Paul Flavius Nechita" rel="nofollow">
                            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                                <img src="https://placeimg.com/380/285/arch" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                                <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignLeft">
                                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-title">@item.Name</div>                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }                                         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

public IActionResult Experience(string sectorid)
    {

        IEnumerable<Sector> sector = sectorRepository.AllActive().ToList();


        return View(sector);
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the enumerable actually contains multiple elements (put a breakpoint in the Razor view to see). Also, have you checked that the elements aren't being outputted to html, but hidden by your css styles?

Comment: You need to figure out if this is a client display issue (to be fixed in HTML / CSS) or a server generation issue (to be fixed in .NET / Razor code). For that, you could use Chrome DevTools to check that the generated HTML code is having only one DIV or more.

Comment: ahh @AdamBrown it was the css styles cheers thats fixed it put up an answer and i will accept it